# Point based rendering

Tags: rendering, point, graphic

I'm writing BSc thesis with topic 'point based rendering'.
I've found some info about this:
[citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.22.3904](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.22.3904&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (PDF), etc...

But it doesn't explain everything. If someone has some knowledge about this and can tell me how to:

- Convert triangle mesh into point clouds and store it
- Display points in interactive frame rate with good quality

My goal is to make something similar to [this video](http://www.gris.uni-tuebingen.de/edu/areas/large/xrendering/video.mpg).

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Would this question be more appropriate at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123706041), it is about point based graphics!

> Point-Based Graphics (The Morgan Kaufmann Series in Computer Graphics)